# Calculate Percentage Of Weight Goal

Tags: c#, math, formula, percentage, calculation

I am trying to find a way to work out the progress percentage towards a weight goal. I have searched and searched and can not find a way or example online.

Language: C#

Example:

Starting Weight: 123.20kg
Current Weight: 120.01kg
Goal: 101.61kg

Comment: This isnt even a programming issue - it is basic grade school arithmetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is to lose `123.20 - 101.61 = 21.59` kg.

So far you have lost `123.20 - 120.01 = 3.19` kg

So you have accomplished `3.19/21.59 = 14.78%` of your goal.